# Google Maps Store Locator Click Jumps to Top of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a Store Locator and every time I click on an anchor (such as Zoom Here, Directions, or Street View), the hash in the href takes me to the top of the page. How can I prevent this from happening? I tried looking through the Store Locator source, but it's minified and hard to figure out what is what. I also tried adding event delegation to anchors with class "action" but this didn't work either.

Main function

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mappanel'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.102683, 10.452576),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var panelDiv = document.getElementById('searchpanel');
    var data = new storeSource;
    var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data, {
        geolocation: false
    });
    new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
        view: view
    });
});
```

storeLocator class

```
/** @extends storeLocator.StaticDataFeed */
function storeSource() {
  jQuery.extend(this, new storeLocator.StaticDataFeed);
  var that = this;
  jQuery.get('/components/com_maps/storeSource.csv', function(data) {
     that.setStores(that.parse_(data));
  });
}

/** @private */
storeSource.prototype.parse_ = function(csv) {
  var stores = [];
  var rows = csv.split('\r');
  var headings = this.parseRow_(rows[0]);
  for (var i = 1, row; row = rows[i]; i++) {
    row = this.toObject_(headings, this.parseRow_(row));
    if(row.adresse.length > 3) {
      row.lat = row.lat.replace(",", ".");
      row.lng = row.lng.replace(",", ".");
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(row.lat, row.lng);
      var locality = this.join_([row.postnr, row.by], ', ');
      var store = new storeLocator.Store(row.uid, position, null, {
        title: row.navn,
        address: this.join_([row.adresse, locality, row.land], '<br>'),
        phone: row.tlfnr
      });
      stores.push(store);
    }
  }
  return stores;
};
/** Joins elements of an array that are non-empty and non-null. */
storeSource.prototype.join_ = function(arr, sep) {
  var parts = [];
  for (var i = 0, ii = arr.length; i < ii; i++) {
    arr[i] && parts.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return parts.join(sep);
};
/*** CSV parsing */
storeSource.prototype.parseRow_ = function(row) {
  // Each row in the CSV file only has ; as delimiter
  row = row.split(';');
  return row;
};
/** Creates an object mapping headings to row elements. */
storeSource.prototype.toObject_ = function(headings, row) {
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0, ii = row.length; i < ii; i++) {
    result[headings[i]] = row[i];
  }
  return result;
};
```

Here's a link to the Store Locator library: http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html

Comment: What does your code look like? Can you provide a link to an example that exhibits the problem (or a jsfiddle)?

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behaviour in the browser for clicking on an `<a>` tag that has an `href` value of `#`. The `#` is reserved for jumping to sections on the page. As an easy example, if you have an `<a>` tag with an `href` of `#movies`, and a section on your page that has a `name` attribute that is also `movies`, then clicking on `<a href="#movies">` will bring the user directly to the `movies` section of your page. If you simply have `#`, then the browser skips to the very top of the page, because you didn't specify a section name.

To prevent this behaviour, you need to do at least this:

```
$(".my-links").on( 'click', function( evt ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

And you may also need to include another line like this (depending on your selector/setup):

```
$(".my-links").on( 'click', function( evt ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

`preventDefault()` will stop the default behaviour for a click on any element that matches the selector. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

`stopPropagation()` will stop the default event from bubbling up the DOM, so it doesn't get caught by any parent elements. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this. I think the `<a>` tags in question are dynamically generated so I used event delegation - `$("#wrapper").on("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`  It didn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, the event delegation should be `$("#wrapper").on("click", "a.action", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`